# Amazon Web service RDS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do i terminate and delete a RDS Instance that is on Amazon Web services . I successfully deleted the rds instance ystd, however it is still incurring charges on me. is it possible that I deleted it wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

If you see charges even after you deleted an RDS instance, make sure:

1. That you didn't reserved a particular instance type ( see here for more details https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/ )
2. That you are checking the right region. ( On the UI right top corner, click through them and check if you don't have instances in other regions ).

If something still not clear contact aws support. They are usually pretty good at responding and helping you troubleshoot issues.

Comment: How do i know if i didnt reserved a particular instance type? How do i check?

Comment: It apepar that i do not have any Reserved Instance as it appear to have no record.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember is that AWS bills on a monthly basis.
Unless you purchased a reserved instance of some type upfront (which is possible for RDS) you will incur a charge at the end of the month for the actual usage of the instance over the monthly billing period, even if you used it for just a few minutes.